# timer with 10milli second resolution android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display a countup timer with format 1.00 resolution. basically seconds and with hundredths of second or 10ms resolution. 
I have tried the chronometer function but still no luck, it seems it can only track 1 second resolution.
here is some of my code:

```
public void stopwatch() {

        stopWatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
        @Override
           public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
            countUpmilli = (Long) ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -arg0.getBase())/   100);
              countUpSec = (Long) ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -arg0.getBase()) / 1000);
               //asText = (countUp / 60) + ":" + (countUp % 60); 
               asText = (countUpSec / 1) + "." + (countUpmilli%100); 

               timertext.setText(asText);

           }
       });
        stopWatch.start();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use System.nanoTime();

Comment: so I can use that within the stopwatch function above? would i replace SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() with System.nanoTime() ? thx